# LOOP,EXCEPTION,CURSOR

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
DECLARE
    DM DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_NAME%TYPE;
    DI EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID%TYPE;
CURSOR ZADANIE5 IS
SELECT DEPARTMENT_NAME,COUNT(DEPARTMENT_ID) FROM DEPARTMENTS
JOIN EMPLOYEES USING(DEPARTMENT_ID)
GROUP BY DEPARTMENT_NAME;
BEGIN
    OPEN ZADANIE5;
    LOOP
        FETCH ZADANIE5 INTO DM,DI;
        IF ZADANIE5%NOTFOUND THEN
        raise_application_error(-20010, ' IN department ' || DM || ' no employees ');
        ELSE
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' In Department ' || DM || ' work ' || DI || ' employees ');
   END IF;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE ZADANIE5;
    END;
```

I have a problem because the program does not work properly. I want it to throw an exception where the employee does not work but the loop repeats and flies again and I get an error that I do not work in accounting but actually  work two of them there

Comment: What does it mean: _where the employee does not work_ ? And what does this mean: _the loop repeats and flies again_ The loop you have written will return all departments. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your code needs many more modifications. It throws error once it finds the department with 0 employees and then the program will exit. Instead of it, you can just print out the information.

You can use `LEFT JOIN` to find all the departments and their employees count even if they have no employees (0 in that case).

```
DECLARE
    DM   DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_NAME%TYPE;
    DI   NUMBER; -- CHANGE HERE
    CURSOR ZADANIE5 IS
    SELECT D.DEPARTMENT_NAME, COUNT(E.DEPARTMENT_ID )
    FROM DEPARTMENTS D
        LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEES E ON ( D.DEPARTMENT_ID = E.DEPARTMENT_ID )
    GROUP BY DEPARTMENT_NAME;
BEGIN
    OPEN ZADANIE5;
    LOOP
        FETCH ZADANIE5 INTO
            DM, DI;
        EXIT WHEN ZADANIE5%NOTFOUND; -- CHANGE HERE
        IF DI = 0 THEN -- CHANGE HERE
--            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20010, ' IN department '
--                                            || DM
--                                            || ' no employees ');
              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' IN department '
                                            || DM
                                            || ' no employees ');
        ELSE
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' In Department '
                                 || DM
                                 || ' work '
                                 || DI
                                 || ' employees ');
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE ZADANIE5;
END;
```

Find the changes in the code and description of the changes inline.

Comment: Hi i changed but it still not working... I mean that it showing better than before because it showing all departments but.... everywhere where no employee is working, it shows that only one is working and  actually should print no employes  " In Department Manufacturing work 1 employees 
 In Department Construction work 1 employees 
 In Department Operations work 1 employees "

Comment: See the updated answer now!! We need to check if Employee table contains any record or not and that is done via `count(E.DEPARTMENT_ID)`. You can also use some `PK` of `EMPLOYEES` table in `COUNT` for better clarity.

Comment: there are records in the department table, i.e. depart.id, which are not in the employees table, but the program does not print that there are no employees with the given department name, it only shows that there is one employee instead of zero

Comment: what should i changed there ? DI   NUMBER; -- CHANGE HERE and here EXIT WHEN ZADANIE5%NOTFOUND; -- CHANGE HERE

Comment: okay its working , my internet is so slowly , thank you MAN for teach!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE
    DM   DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_NAME%TYPE;
    DI   NUMBER; -- CHANGE HERE
    CURSOR ZADANIE5 IS
    SELECT DEPARTMENT_NAME, COUNT(DEPARTMENT_ID)
    FROM DEPARTMENTS
        LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEES USING ( DEPARTMENT_ID )
    GROUP BY DEPARTMENT_NAME;
BEGIN
    OPEN ZADANIE5;
    LOOP
        FETCH ZADANIE5 INTO
            DM, DI;
        EXIT WHEN ZADANIE5%NOTFOUND; -- CHANGE HERE
        IF DI = 0 THEN 

              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' IN department '
                                            || DM
                                            || ' no employees ');
        ELSE
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' In Department '
                                 || DM
                                 || ' work '
                                 || DI
                                 || ' employees ');
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE ZADANIE5;
END;


In Department Sales work 34 employees 
 In Department Control And Credit work 1 employees 
 In Department Recruiting work 1 employees 
 In Department Corporate Tax work 1 employees 
 In Department IT Support work 1 employees 
 In Department Government Sales work 1 employees 
 In Department Retail Sales work 1 employees 
 In Department Marketing work 2 employees 
 In Department IT Helpdesk work 1 employees 
 In Department Administration work 1 employees 
 In Department Purchasing work 6 employees 
 In Department Contracting work 1 employees 
 In Department NOC work 1 employees 
 In Department Shipping work 45 employees 
 In Department IT work 5 employees 
 In Department Executive work 3 employees 
 In Department Finance work 6 employees 
 In Department Public Relations work 1 employees 
 In Department Shareholder Services work 1 employees 
 In Department Benefits work 1 employees 
 In Department Payroll work 1 employees 
 In Department Human Resources work 1 employees 
 In Department Accounting work 2 employees 
 In Department Treasury work 1 employees 
 In Department Manufacturing work 1 employees 
 In Department Construction work 1 employees 
 In Department Operations work 1 employees
```

everywhere where is 1 employee should print no employes